# How to dynamically create a class out of the DataContext, in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to dynamically get the binding properties for a view into a class and manipulate it in run time.
for example, if the `DataContext` is of type `User` that has 10 properties, but the bound properties are only 4, can I make a class that has these 4 properties only?

Comment: It is possible.  What exactly is the goal you are trying to achieve here though?

Comment: I want to serialize the data appearing in the view, and I want to get it as short string as I can, so I want to exclude the unbound properties

Comment: sometimes the DataContext class has dozens of properties and collections, but what is shown in a specific view just few properties, so serializing this mini-class would save me a lot

Comment: Ok.  I see what you mean now.  I am not sure if that is possible in the way you want.

Comment: If you have it working - post your code, please. Would be very useful!

Comment: Hi Mohamed, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Doable, but difficult.

1. You must parse the visual tree, and visit every control using VisualTreeHelper (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/874426/275330).
2. For every control you can get a list of its dependency properties (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26367132/275330)
3. Then for each separate dependency property you can check if its value is set locally (see: [Knowing if a DependencyProperty has not been set in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798104/275330)). If so - you have the value you need.

I've never used 1+2+3 together, so I don't know what additional difficulties you may have.